Studies with White being on top
"There is an essential distinction between a chess problem and a composed endgame. In an endgame the solver has to demonstrate a win or draw for white against a superior, or at least an equal force [...]" (Kenneth Howard, "The Enjoyment of Chess Problems")
"Mostly." (H.R.)
I immediately recalled studies by Korolkov et al. (e.g. triple bishop underpromotion!), where White would easily win, if it weren't for Black trying to escape into a stalemate. (This is the standard case where White has problems with winning while having materially a vastly superior force.)
Note this can as well happen in an OTB game. I immediately also recall this swindle. Black is a rook up - temporarily. (He should lose, therefore the position usually is "beautified".)
It is tempting to ask for the record: Which is the study or OTB game where White (or Black) has a maximum of surplus force, but must struggle heavily to net the win? (As usual, Q=8 R=5 B,N=3 P=1.) "Cheating" is allowed: Black having eight pawns on the seventh rank is hard to fight against. Also one black pawn is enough to let White struggle, if it threatens mate.
